# How do I get the computer name from an IP Address in Unix

Tags: networking, unix

I want to find a computer on my network, I have the IP address but not the name. How do I get the name?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `host ip-address` (obviously replacing ip-address by the actual IP address). Check `man host` for options. Alternatively `dig` or `nslookup`.

Comment: It would appear you type faster than me - exactly what I was going to say :)

Comment: Specifically, `dig -x`